# When assign element of array to another, unexpected value contained

Tags: c, arrays

I'm learning C language by my self. 
When I assign one array value of element to another, (looks) strange thing happens.
My Code is below.

```
int main(void){
    int i =0; 
    char a2[] = "aaaa";
    char a1[] = "bbb";

    printf("%lu\n",sizeof(a2));
    printf("%lu\n",sizeof(a1));
    printf("%c\n",a2[4]);
    printf("---\n");
    for(i =0; i < sizeof(a2); i++){
        a2[i]=a1[i];
        printf("%c\n", a2[i]);
    }
    printf("---\n");
    printf("%c\n", a2[4]);

    return 0;
}
```

result is below.

```
5
4

---
b
b
b

b
---
b
```

I have no idea why <strike>a[4]</strike> a2[4] value is "b". 
Firstly, I thought that if I try to compile this code, compiler would through error, but it says OK.
So I show the result and saw the a2[4] element contain "b" character. 
How array works in C?

What should I have to learn the notion for the deeper understand of mechanism?

Comment: Note: when printing a `size_t` value, use `"%zu"` rather than `"%lu"`.

Comment: Note: using `char a2[] = "abcd"; char a1[] = "efg";` likely would helped lead to a deeper understanding.

Comment: Thanks **chux**! I have to try that case.

Answer (score 6):

As it has already been pointed out when you do the following you will get undefined behavior:

```
for(i =0; i < sizeof(a2); i++){
    a2[i]=a1[i];
    printf("%c\n", a2[i]);
}
```

This is because the size of `a2` is 5 and the size of `a1` is 4 so you have accessed the fifth element of `a1` (`a1[4]`) which is going beyond the array.  So when you do `a2[4] = a1[4]`, which is what the last iteration of your `for` loop is doing you could be assigning any value to `a2[4]` since the value of `a1[4]` is not well defined.  So even though `a2[4]` is a valid element in the array you have assigned something to it that is not well defined and when you print `a2[4]` you could be printing anything.  See the last paragraph for an explanation of why you are most likely getting `b`.

There are a few things to remember with this.  First arrays are zero based indexed and second strings in C are null terminated so `sizeof("aa")` is actually 3 not 2.

Since your program has undefined behavior it could print anything as any value could be in a1[4].  Having said that if the compiler placed the array `a2` right after `a1` you would consistently see `b` printed as you assigned the value `b` to `a2[0]` in the first iteration of your loop.  This is just one possible explanation for why you are seeing a `b`.  The compiler does not have to place the arrays in this position and in fact on my machine it does not place the arrays in this position.  This is what it means when behavior is undefined in C.

Answer (score 1):

"why `a[4]` value is `"b"`" is incorrect. (Certainly OP means `a2` here.)

Note that the size of `a2` is printed as 5.  The following does *not* access outside the array bounds of `a2`.  Instead code is simply printing the null character `'\0'` initially, and then ....

```
char a2[] = "aaaa";
....
printf("%c\n",a2[4]);
```

Code enters *undefined behavior* with the below loop in the last iteration as `a2[4] = a1[4];` accesses `a1` outside its 4 `char` size.  So the rest of code behavior is *undefined*.

```
char a1[] = "bbb";
...
for(i =0; i < sizeof(a2); i++){
    a2[i]=a1[i];
    printf("%c\n", a2[i]);
}
```